# How can I modify a vector from outside the class

Tags: c++, vector, objective-c++

How can I get the access to a private vector outside the class? I want to  modify parameters of this objects.

I try to make getter and return the vector by reference, but when I try to change parameters of objects included in vector in main functions changes in vector are not saved.

```
class Restaurant
{
    std::vector <Waiter> waiters_vector_;

public:
     inline std::vector<Waiter> &GetWaitersVector() { return waiters_vector_; }      

     void Restaurant::AddWaiter(Waiter tmp)
{
          waiters_vector_.push_back(tmp);
}
     Restaurant();
    ~Restaurant();
};


class Waiter
{
    int current_group_id_=0;
public:
    int GetCurrentGroupId()
{
    return current_group_id_;
}

void SetCurrentGroupId(int tmp)

{
    current_group_id_ = tmp;
}

    Waiter();
    ~Waiter();
};


int main()
{  

    Restaurant restaurant1;
    Waiter w1, w2, w3;
    restaurant1.AddWaiter(w1);
    restaurant1.AddWaiter(w2);
    restaurant1.AddWaiter(w3);

    for (Waiter element : restaurant1.GetWaitersVector())
{
        element.SetCurrentGroupId(123);
}

    for (Waiter element : restaurant1.GetWaitersVector())
{
        std::cout << element.GetCurrentGroupId() << std::endl;
}

}
```

result:
0 
0 
0

Comment: A note on software design: The whole point of making the vector private is to control the class’ interface and its communication with the rest of the code. Exposing the vector via a getter makes this almost completely moot, and violates the “tell, don’t ask” design principle. Rather than provide direct access, the class should selectively provide methods for modifying only those aspects that actually need modifying (And these should be as few as possible, ideally none).

Comment: Compile error:  "  void Restaurant::AddWaiter(Waiter tmp) "  inside of  declaration gives " error: extra qualification ‘Restaurant::’ on member ‘AddWaiter’ [-fpermissive] "

Comment: `~Restaurant();` probably wants to be `~Restaurant() = default;`

Answer (score 5):

Both of your `for` loops are making copies

```
for (Waiter element : restaurant1.GetWaitersVector())
```

you want to modify references to the actual objects

```
for (Waiter& element : restaurant1.GetWaitersVector())
```

Comment: The first loop is making copies of EACH ELEMENT ITERATED OVER, whose scope is the loop itself (i.e. destroyed at the end of the current iteration).  Just thought I'd add that for a little clarity.  Your answer is simple and to the point!

Answer (score 2):

`for (Waiter element : restaurant1.GetWaitersVector())` operates with a copy of the vector.

If you want to operate on the reference use

```
for (auto& element : restaurant1.GetWaitersVector())
  // ^^^^^
```

instead.

---

But besides what's mentioned above, exposing your interned vector is a bad design idea. You should rather have a getter that does

```
inline const std::vector<Waiter> &GetWaitersVector() const { return waiters_vector_; }
```

and thus force clients accessing it to use specific functions of your class like `AddWaiter()` to modify it.

Comment: Pretty sure `auto element` is **not** a reference but a copy. Did you mean `Waiter& element`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I wasn't that sure if `auto` should deduce the reference automatically, ty for the clarification.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ AFAIK `auto` never deduces reference.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - That's very true.

Comment: You say *"operates with a copy of the vector"* but I think you mean "operates with a copy of the element" no?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the access to a private vector outside the class? I want to modify parameters of this objects.

You don't. Or rather, you need to decide:  Is the vector of  waiters something private, or isn't it? Is it an implementation detail that code using this class should not be aware of? If not, do you really want to be able to manipulate it as-is on the outside? Or perhaps you want to use the [PIMPL idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) to provide a `.waiters()` method which returns an obscure class, with methods such as `add(...)`, `remove(...),  etc.?

Those are design decisions for you to make.